# Add tool tip to Asp Drop-down list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, tooltip

When I  add a tool tip attribute to asp drop-down list, its not showing any tool tip,When I include this drop-down in the div tag and give title attribute for the div tag, then i can see the tool-tip.

```
<div title="Professions">
<asp:Dropdownlist runat="server" ID="ddlProfession" DataValueField="ProfessionName" DataTextField="ProfessionName" Width="260px">
</asp:Dropdownlist>
</div>
```

But I don't want to add any extra div or any other container. directly i want the drop-down to show the tool tip.even it is fine, if you can guide me how to add title attribute for input tag of asp drop-down list which comes after rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:-

```
<asp:Dropdownlist runat="server" ID="ddlProfession" DataValueField="ProfessionName"
    DataTextField="ProfessionName" Width="260px" ToolTip="Some Text">
</asp:Dropdownlist>
```

Please note it will render Html `select` with title attribute as `Some Text`. So you don't need any extra div.